# drop duplicates pandas still keep the last two row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I want to drop duplicates from `dataframe` but, when I do that it always keeps the last two rows with the same `id` at this matter.

Also I found it interesting when I use that on python interpreter on command prompt it takes all the duplicates with the same code!

But, when I run the file `python train.py` it always keep the last two.

THE FILE:

```
        data=pd.read_csv("Employee\Employee.csv")
        data.loc[len(data)] = [Id , name, dept, shift] #input data here
        print(data)
        data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='last')
        print(data)
        fileName="Employee\Employee.csv"
        data.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
```

Comment: Well, then, they aren't really the same.  Extra newline, maybe?

Comment: yeah extra new line, how did that make them aren't really the same?

Comment: but you can see the operation is still in the dataframe form before converted to `.csv`

Comment: hmm. pandas isn't broken. so you're probably doing something wrong/inconsistent. Check out this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - we need to be able to replicate what you're doing in order to diagnose the issue. and usually, creating such an example will illustrate what's going wrong! good luck :)

Comment: I've been done that using python interpreter and it drop all duplicates! but my problems when I move that code to file, it won't drop all dulpicates instead keep the last two rows @MichaelDelgado

Comment: but hey, I've found the answer somehow :)

Comment: if that's true, I'd encourage you to post the code and a repeatable example! would make a very important bug report for the pandas developers. but I expect something is going wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do stupid things but the matter is IT WORKS!

just simply add this code below:

```
        data=pd.read_csv(fileName)
        data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='last')
        data.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
```

so the final form is this:

```
        data=pd.read_csv("Employee\Employee.csv")
        data.loc[len(data)] = [Id , name, dept, shift] #input data here
        print(data)
        data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='last')
        print(data)
        fileName="Employee\Employee.csv"
        data.to_csv(fileName,index=False)

        data=pd.read_csv(fileName)
        data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='last')
        data.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
```

I know it looks like boiler plate code, but if someone know how to do it more make sense, I will be pleased if you comment down below

Comment: this is not a fix.... this is a hack. all you are doing is reading it again, droppping and writing back to csv. Try to find out y it dint work in the first attempt. This solution is not scalable.

Comment: if only you can give me shed of light on what is going wrong

Comment: can u obfuscate the date in that file and add it to ur question. So I can replicate and see whats wrong